# Jolt Transform to Array with Parent Attributes

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I am using NiFi Jolt Processor to transform some JSON data.

My JSON field genre contains shared attributes and an array that contains the list of actual genre names.

I needed to transform the "genre" attribute to become an array of "genres" containing the list of the common attributes and the different genre names.

I have the following input JSON:

```
{
  "programIdentifier": "9184663",
  "programInstance": {
    "genre": {
      "source": "GN",
      "locked": false,
      "lastModifiedDate": 1527505462094,
      "lastModifiedBy": "Some Service",
      "genres": [
        "Miniseries",
        "Drama"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried the following spec:

```
[{
  "operation": "shift",
   "spec": {
     "programIdentifier": ".&",,
     "genre": {
        "source": "genres[].source.value",
        "locked": "genres[].locked",
        "lastModifiedDate": "genres[].lastModifiedDate",
        "lastModifiedBy": "genres[].lastModifiedBy",
        "genres": {
            "*": "genres[&0].name"                
        }
     }
}]
```

This my expected output:

```
{
  "programIdentifier": "9184663",
  "programInstance": {
    "genres": [
      {
        "source": {
          value: "GN"
        }
        "locked": false,
        "lastModifiedDate": 1527505462094,
        "lastModifiedBy": "Some Service",
        "name": "Miniseries"
      },
      {
        "source": {
          value: "GN"
        }
        "locked": false,
        "lastModifiedDate": 1527505462094,
        "lastModifiedBy": "Some Service",
        "name": "Drama"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But it's coming out as:

```
{
  "programIdentifier": "9184663",
  "programInstance": {
    "genres": [
      {
    "source": {
      "value": "GN"
    },
    "name": "Miniseries"
       }, {
    "locked": false,
    "name": "Drama"
       }, {
    "lastModifiedDate": 1527505462094
       }, {
    "lastModifiedBy": "Some Service"
       }],
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it what you want to achieve?

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "programIdentifier": ".&",
      "programInstance": {
        "genre": {
          "genres": {
            "*": {
              "@2": {
                "source": "programInstance.genres[&2].source[]",
                "locked": "programInstance.genres[&2].locked",
                "lastModifiedDate": "programInstance.genres[&2].lastModifiedDate",
                "lastModifiedBy": "programInstance.genres[&2].lastModifiedBy"
              },
              "@": "programInstance.genres[&1].name"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: You're a star Magda! Thanks!